# How do I redirect links?

Tags: php, facebook, redirect

I have created one application for my portfolio.

Let's say the URL is `http://fb.domain.com/about/` and my FB app is `http://apps.facebook.com/myap/about/`.

A user can access `http://fb.domain.com/about/` directly from my site.

If the user types `http://fb.domain.com/about/` or clicks `http://fb.domain.com/about/`, how do I redirect them to `http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/about/`

Here's an example from http://www.oodle.com.

If you go to [this link](http://facebook.oodle.com/info/safety_guidelines/), you will be redirected to [here](http://apps.facebook.com/marketplace/info/safety_guidelines/).

How is that done? Let me know. I currently use php for my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ModRewrite in your .htaccess to redirect based on the rules set, which is probably the cleanest solution without involving hardcoding redirects in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
// Define current URL
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$query = !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : null;
$url = !empty($query) ? "http://$host$self?$query" : "http://$host$self";

// If current URL is not Facebook's, redirect to Facebook
if($url == 'http://fb.domain.com/about/'){
 header("Location: http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/about/");
 exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all you need is the simple redirect, no page loading, then this should do it...

```
header("Location: http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/about/");
exit();
```

Comment: How script will detect if user access it directly or from facebook? If already in facebook should redirect it again?

Comment: The script would run from the primary site, not the facebook application. If you are using apache, or something that supports .htaccess, I would go with the other answer though. ;)